# Default location of simplepie cache

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, simplepie

I am using `fetch_feed()` to parse RSS feeds. `fetch_feed()` does auto caching.

How can I test if my feeds are being cached with the correct time interval? and where is the default location of the cache?

I have used wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime hook to set the time interval.

Answer (score 0):

SimplePie stores the cached articles in the `/cache` directory by default, although their documentation states: "SimplePie includes a caching system which can be used with a file-based cache, database cache or a Memcache-backed cache system."

The default cache duration is one hour (3600 ms). You can override it however with the `set_cache_duration` function. Make sure you have the cache folder permissions set to at least 755.